# Django FormWizard and Admin application

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a series of forms that I need a user to complete in sequence, which is perfect for the formwizard app. However, I've some need of the admin application also and would like to set the whole thing up to trigger several forms within the admin app.

Is it possible/easy to integrate a 'formwizard' into the admin application?

If not, is extending the admin template a viable option and hooking the rest up manually? Opinions?

Update:
Some clarity in my 'problem'.

I wanted to use the admin app as I was thinking I only needed basic modelforms - one perhaps split across many forms, which would have been the role of formwizard.

What I have:

Form 1: 10 yes/no questions (each yes corresponds to a new form that needs to be filled out)
if yes is ticked, the corresponding forms are put into a formwizard and displayed for the user to complete.

---

However the suggested option (modelforms + styling) would take care of the majority of my concerns I guess - and is the seemingly simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a *lot* that you can do, but you'd need to be more specific about what you mean by "integrate a formwizard into the admin app" and "trigger several forms within the admin app."

The admin app at its core is basically just a wrapper around a bunch of stock ModelForms, so if you just build a formwizard using ModelForms and slap the admin styling on it, you may be 80% of the way there.

Answer (score -3):

You *do* have the source, and it *is* Python, so... you can read the admin application source to see what options it has.

Look at 
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates.
It appears that you can override templates easily.  They even provide step-by-step instructions for adding your own customized admin templates.

Comment: "it doesn't have a lot of integration points" - sorry, that's just flat-out wrong, and has been since the newforms-admin merge back in June or July.